# how to play more than one mp3 in phonegap

Tags: cordova, mp3, media, playback

i have some problem with my app.

i was buliding hijaiyah aplication with PhoneGap and jquery mobile, i have some problem in it. actually this is working, but this is very delay to play another sound.
here's html

```
<div data-role=page id=win8 >
  <div data-role=header data-theme=b>
  <a href="index1.html" data-role=button data-icon=arrow-l>Home</a>
    <h1>Dal</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role=content>

     <p style="width:100%;text-align:center;"> <input type="image" onclick="playAudio('big_dal.mp3')" data-role="none" src=image/8.png /></p> 
     <div class=ui-grid-b>
      <div class=ui-block-a><input type="image" data-role="none" src=image/8da.png />
      <div data-role="button" data-mini="true" onclick="playAudio('8_da.mp3')">Play</div></div>
      <div class=ui-block-b><input type="image" data-role="none" src=image/8di.png />
      <div data-role="button" data-mini="true" onclick="playAudio('8_di.mp3')">Play</div></div>
      <div class=ui-block-c><input type="image" data-role="none" src=image/8du.png />
      <div data-role="button" data-mini="true" onclick="playAudio('8_du.mp3')">Play</div></div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's the javascript

```
function playAudio(src) {
            if (device.platform == 'Android') {
                src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
            }

            var media = new Media(src, success, error_error);

            media.play();
        }

        function success() {
            // ignore
        }

        function error_error(e) {
            alert('mmmm, salah!');
            alert(e.message);
        }
```

what's the solution for this problem? i mean how to resolve this delay. this is so make me confused. thanks anyway.
Hasan Fathy, sory for bad english.